# PHP Class Variables Reassignment

Tags: php, class, properties

Is it possible to make the following  bar() method return "blue"?

```
class TestClass
{
    public $var1 = "red";

    public function foo() //returns red
        {
            return $this->var1;
        }

    public function bar() //still returns red
        {
            $this->var1 = "blue";

            return $this->var1;
        }
}
```

I know that class properties can't be variables, results of addition, etc. I read about overloading using __set and __get, however that seems to be geared towards totally dynamic properties.

Comment: It does [return blue](http://ideone.com/t2Tla)?

Comment: The above returns "blue" for me on PHP 3.5.3 when I follow it with `$t = new TestClass; echo $t->bar();`. How are you calling `bar()`? Since `$var1` is non-static, it is an instance property instead of a class property.

Comment: I think you mean 5.3.3? Or you got a helluva old version of PHP David =)

Comment: @Tim Cooper - +1 That site is wicked cool.

Comment: @PatrikAkerstrand - LOL, yes. Too much time with PHPUnit. ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code currently works as you describe it.  From the PHP interactive shell:

```
php > $t = new TestClass();
php > echo $t->foo();
red
php > echo $t->bar();
blue
php > echo $t->foo();
blue
```

Perhaps you can explain your problem in a different way?

Comment: same for me, works perfectly fine and I see no reason why it shouldn't

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I got it working. It was a typo all along.

Answer (score 0):

You can update bar() method as set bar with optional parameter.

public function bar($mycolor='red') 
{
      $this->var1 = $mycolor;
      return $this->var1;
}